# Android navigation component: How to get the current navigation graph's id?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am using nested navigation graphs in order to scope and share my viewmodels across a set of fragments.

I also have a BaseFragment class which obtains the reference to the required viewmodel:

```
fun provideViewModel() : VM {
        return if(viewModelScopeGraphId != null) {
            ViewModelProvider(findNavController().getViewModelStoreOwner(viewModelScopeGraphId!!)).get(viewModelClass)
        } else {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(viewModelClass)
        }
     }
```

I can override a property, `viewModelScopeGraphId`, if I need the viewmodel to be scoped to the navigation graph (or nested navigation graph) with that specific id.
Ideally I would just want to set a boolean flag like `useScopedViewModel` and obtain the id of the current navigation graph, for example:

```
fun provideViewModel() : VM {
        return if(useScopedViewModel) {
            ViewModelProvider(findNavController().getViewModelStoreOwner(getCurrentNavGraphId())).get(viewModelClass)
        } else {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(viewModelClass)
        }
     }
```

I have tried using `navController.graph.id` to get the current graph id, but it seems the id I get from there does not match up with my resource id's (eg. `R.id.nav_graph`). Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue (more context of my case at the end), tried a few solutions, none successful.

In the end, I give up and just give the graph id as a parameter for the Fragment.

As it could help you to achieve your own solution, so my solution looks like the following:

- Have to create this extension, as the original `navGraphViewModels` only accepts a `@IdRes navGraphId: Int` and I want to lazy load the arguments, etc. (Also I've simplified removing the `factoryProducer` from the arguments, as so far I will not use it for our solution.

```
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.navGraphViewModels(
        noinline graphIdProducer: () -> Int
): Lazy<VM> {
    val backStackEntry by lazy {
        findNavController().getBackStackEntry(graphIdProducer())
    }
    val storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore = {
        backStackEntry.viewModelStore
    }
    return createViewModelLazy(VM::class, storeProducer, {
        backStackEntry.defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    })
}
```

- In my fragment where I want to use it, I recover the Arguments using the `navArgs`, and recover the `ViewModel` using the extension above:

```
    private val listenerViewModel: ListenerViewModel by navGraphViewModels {
        navArgs.graphId
    }

    private val navArgs: MyFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

- And to whoever needs to "listen" for that `ViewModel`, can simply load using the Navigation `navGraphViewModels`:

```
    private val listenerViewModel: ListenerViewModel by navGraphViewModels(
            R.id.my_graph_a
    )
```

- And from another graph/fragment I simple do:

```
    private val listenerViewModel: ListenerViewModel by navGraphViewModels(
            R.id.my_graph_b
    )
```

To explain a little the context of my case:

- I have two distinct Fragments, where the user can click in a Country selection.

  - Each of these Fragments is inside a different Graph, as they are different flows.
- The Country selection is a Fragment where load the supported countries list from an API, displays it, pre-select any previous user selection (also given as a FragmentArgs), and the user can change the selection, which implies coming back to the previous screen, with the newly selected value or just come back not triggering anything here.
- I'm aware and expecting the release of https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220, but as it is today (March-2020) it is only available in `alpha`.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to check it with graph's start destination.

```
when (navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
    R.id.firstFragmentOfFirstGraph -> { /* First graph */ }
    R.id.firstFragmentOfSecondGraph -> { /* Second graph */}
}
```