# How to find the current graphId of android navigation component

Tags: android, navigation

I am using Android navigation component and I want to create a viewModel with the current graph scope.
I need to use `navGraphViewModels(graphId)`.
the problem is that I use current fragment inside different graphs. how should I get graphId runtime based on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no official method of doing that.

None of the options that I've thought about are super good, but you could try a few different approaches:

You could store this id globally, or pass it through all the fragments. Not beautiful but this guy made it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60819820/3005235

You could probably use the way `navGraphViewModels` works and hack your way to find the id.

[image: Documentation from android]

*"This property can be accessed only after this NavGraph is on the NavController back stack, and an attempt access prior to that will result in an IllegalArgumentException."*

Using this information, you could try having a list of the all possible different graphs ids, try/catch the *viewModel* assignment using `navGraphViewModels` with each one of them and you will find the current one when the exception is not thrown. Not nice but maybe it could work.

But I would say that the limitation of not being able to get the current `graphId` says something more about how *Navigation* works and that maybe you are looking for something else... `navGraphViewModels(graphId)` works by checking the `NavController` backstack, if there is a `NavBackStackEntry` referenced by the `graphId` and that is a instance of `NavGraph`, it uses that NavBackStackEntry as the ViewModelStoreOwner that is needed to the `navGraphViewModels` internals (https://androidx.tech/artifacts/navigation/navigation-fragment-ktx/2.2.0-source/androidx/navigation/NavGraphViewModelLazy.kt.html). The thing about not being able to get the current `graphId` is because it is possible to have more than one `NavGraph` currently in the backstack (if you navigate from one graph to another), so what is the current one? Is it the one closer to the top of the backstack?

I've tried thinking about your problem as needing to create a `viewModel` with the current backstack scope, something like changing

`val viewModel by navGraphViewModels(graphId)`

to

`val viewModel by viewModels(navBackStackEntry)`

and pass the first `navBackStackEntry`, to have the outermost scope, but maybe it is not what you want.

`viewModels()` delegate simply needs a `ViewModelStoreOwner` (which every `NavBackStackEntry` is one)

And as I've said, `navGraphViewModels(graphId)` works by finding the navBackStackEntry associated to this `graphId` and using it as the `ViewModelStoreOwner`, you would be doing a similar thing but to create a specific `NavBackStackEntry` scoped *viewModel* and not a 'current' graph scoped. You probably want the last entry from the *NavBackStack*, to make it work as scoping by the graphId would? This way is probably a little bit complicated but you would have more control over the scope that you want to use.

I've also thought of checking all the *NavBackStackEntries* and finding one that is related to a `NavGraph` and you could use that with `by viewModels` and achieve almost the same effect as `navGraphViewModels` but sadly it is not possible:

[image: Android Documentation reference]

I hope this investigation can help you, somehow. After all that, try/catching all possible `graphIds` may be a valid workaround.